# Show records where column have more than 1 unique value

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to build a query displaying data where column 1 have more than 1 unique value in column 2 and display both records. For example:

```
COL1        COL2
----------------
Andy       White
Andy       Brown
Andy       Brown
Andy       Brown
Jess       Green
Jess       Green
Jess       Green
```

As you can see Andy have more than 1 unique value in COL2
I would like to display both of them, ideally showing the rest of the columns as well (select *)

```
COL1       COL2       COL3       COL4
-------------------------------------
Andy      White       data       data
Andy      Brown       data       data
```

I do not need to display values for Jess as all values in COL2 are the same.

I tried to find SQL query already but unfortunately nothing matched my searches.

Comment: Your results don't really make sense.  What is `'data'`?

Comment: `data` is some additional information from the table which is unique for every record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the list of names:

```
select distinct col1, col2
from (select col1, col2, count(distinct col2) over (partition by col1) cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt >= 2;
```

Or alternatively:

```
select distinct col1, col2
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 <> t.col2);
```

You can add:

```
select distinct col1, col2, 'data' as col3, 'data' as col4
```

but that doesn't seem particularly useful.

Comment: i would like to add to your first query additional column to display some more data, where to put it to keep the same sorting (ordering) of column 1 and column 2? @gordon-linoff

Comment: @serious_booze . . . That would be a different question.  Can you ask a new question with sample data and desired results.